# what does latDist mean in sumo traci.vehicle.changeSublane(vehID, latDist)?

Tags: sumo

I want to know something more about the latDist component in traci.vehicle.changeSublane(vehID, latDist) rather than what sumo says in "https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State.html#lane_change_mode_0xb6". Does it have any interval? Do the values it takes are the matter of distance? Does it have values as threshold? What do we mean when using for instance "3.00" as latDist?
Best,
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SUMO's sublane model every vehicle has a continuous lateral position meaning it can be freely positioned in the boundaries of the edge, occupying one or more sublanes. This means a "lane change" is nothing more than a lateral movement. To make it independent of the actual sublane width (which has not so much relevance in reality) the offset to change is now given in meters and not in lane (or sublane) numbers. So an offset of 3.0 means move 3 meters to the left (in a right hand driven network).

Comment: So, the latDist can take on the values from (-lanewidth/2) to (lanewidth/2)?

Comment: It depends on where your vehicle currently is. If your current lateral position is y, then the limits are -y and edgewidth-y.

Comment: 1 - May this lateral movement be stopped by some factors? 2 - Can we say that by assigning this value, the vehicle is permitted to have a nonstop lateral movement from the departPos to the arrivalPos?

Comment: 1. Yes, if it is not possible to do a safe lateral change it will not be performed. 2. The movement will start immediately and will be performed until it is either completed or interrupted (see 1.)

Comment: Then, 1 - is it possible to use lane-change model attributes like lcPushy, lcAssertive,... when defining the route file and traci.vehicle.changeSublane(vehID, latDist) in python code at the same time? 2 - What does " This will override any other lane change motivations but conform to
safety-constraints as configured by laneChangeMode" mean? Does it mean that there is any conflict between this method and other definitions? 3 - What is the role of the traci.vehicle.setLaneChangeMode(vehID, lcm)? Is it prior to  traci.vehicle.changeSublane(vehID, latDist)?